# 空ディレクトリを、そのパスを表示しながら再帰的に削除するには?

Tags: shellscript, unix

今、あるディレクトリに対して、その中にある空ディレクトリを、そのディレクトリのパスを表示しながら再帰的に削除したいと考えています。

再帰的な削除とは、例えばあるディレクトリが空なので削除した場合に、その親ディレクトリも空になったので、親も削除する、というような挙動です。

少し調べてみた結果、 `find target-dir -type d -empty -delete` をすると、このような削除ができるのだと理解したのですが、しかしこのコマンドでは削除したディレクトリが何だったのかの表示をしてくれないな、と思っています。

これを実現する方法はありますでしょうか?

Comment: 最後に `-print` を付ければ良いでしょう。`find target-dir -type d -empty -delete -print`

Comment: 補足として、`GNU find(1)` の `EXPRESSION` セクションには **Actions which inhibit the default -print are -delete**, -exec, -execdir, -ok, -okdir, -fls, -fprint, -fprintf, -ls, -print and -printf.  との記載があります。